# If $F$ is a formally real field then is $F(\alpha)$ formally real?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let us call a field $F$ $\textit{ formally real }$ if $-1$ is not expressible as a sum of squares in $F$. Now suppose $F$ is a formally real field and $f(x)\in F[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial of odd degree and $\alpha $ is a root of $f(x)$. Is it true that $F(\alpha)$ is also formally real ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and [here](http://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2012/01/18/odd-degree-extensions-of-formally-real-fields-are-formally-real/) is a proof. ${} {} {}$