# Dummit Foote Exercise 13.3.15

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

A Field F is said to be formally real if $-1$ can not be written as sum of squares in F.
let $f(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$ of odd degree with $\alpha$ as a root.

Now the Question is Prove that $F(\alpha)$ is also Formally real.

What i have done so far is to check that i can not exclude the condition of degree of $f(x)$ being odd. If $f(x)$ is of even order then this need not be the case. For example for  $f(x)=x^2+1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ we have $i$ as a root and in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ we have $-1=i^2$. So, i have to use that $f(x)$ is a polynomial of odd degree.

But i am unable to decide how to proceed with this.

Before this exercise there is an exercise if $[F(\alpha):F]$ is odd then $F(\alpha)=F(\alpha^2)$. I have proved this already. I somehow feel i should use this result to prove given result.

But no progress in this way too..

Any small hint would be appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: This question was already posted [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169111/if-f-is-a-formally-real-field-then-is-f-alpha-formally-real) and was answered with a link to a full proof. _Don't_ read it, if you only want a small hint.

Comment: ok, i do not prefer to read it. Could you please give some hint for further approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read the hint given in the book? For example suppose there is an irreducible polynomial $f$ of odd degree such that $F(\alpha)$ is not formally real, $\alpha$ a root of $f$. Choose such an irreducible polynomial of minimal degree. If $-1$ can be written as a sum of squares $p_1(\alpha)^2,\ldots,p_m(\alpha)^2$ then this means we have an equation

$$-1 = p_1(\alpha)^2 + \ldots + p_m(\alpha)^2.$$

So this means that under the isomorphism $F(\alpha) \cong F[x]/(f(x))$, the element $\alpha$ on the L.H.S corresponds to $\overline{x}$ the residue of $x$ in the quotient. So this means in the quotient ring we have

$$-1 = p_1(\overline{x})^2 + \ldots + p_m(\overline{x})^2$$

and so therefore in the polynomial ring $F[x]$ we have an equation $-1 + f(x)g(x) = p_1(x)^2 + \ldots + p_m(x)^2$. So by comparing degrees, we see that $\deg g$ is odd and furthermore $\deg g < \deg f$.

> > **Question 1:** Why is $\deg g < \deg f$? Hint: What is the maximal degree that a "polynomial"  $p(\overline{x})$ in the quotient can have?
> >
> > **Question 2:** I have spelt out enough details, can you use the hint in Dummit and Foote to complete the rest?

Comment: For Question 1 :

all $p_i(\bar{x})$ are in Quotient field, So, must have degree less than that of $p(x)$.

$deg(f(x)g(x))$ has to be equal to degree of $p_1(\overline{x})^2 + \ldots + p_m(\overline{x})^2$.

So, degree of $(f(x)g(x))$ must be even and as $f(x)$ is of odd degree degree of $g(x)$ should also be odd.

degree of $p_1(\overline{x})^2 + \ldots + p_m(\overline{x})^2$ is less than 2 times that of degree of f(x).

So, degree of $f(x)g(x)$ should also be less than 2 times that of degree of $f(x)$ for this we need degree of $g(x)$ less than that of f(x).

Comment: For Question 2 : There are no hints in my  Dummit Foote book. I am having Indian Edition. May be in Some editions they have not included.

What i am guessing is that we have taken degree of f(x) to be minimum with given property but we have 
$-1 + f(x)g(x) = p_1(x)^2 + \ldots + p_m(x)^2$ So, Now g(x) plays the role of f(x) and we have 

$-1 = p_1(\overline{x})^2 + \ldots + p_m(\overline{x})^2$ over $F(\alpha_1) \cong F[x]/(g(x))$ This is a contradiction as we have assumed f(x) is polynomial of minimal degree with this property.

Though I see some small gaps in between i hope i will clear it.

Comment: i have to take some extra care as i am assuming $g(x)$ to be irreducible in this case as it may not be always.

Just now i have seen this answer, So  i thought i will first express my views and then check for edits :)